# Internal server error when trying to seeInLastEmail using Mailcatcher and Codeception

Tags: php, codeception, mailcatcher

I am using the captbariton mailcatcher module for Codeception (https://github.com/captbaritone/codeception-mailcatcher-module). The system 
is run on a local XAMPP-installation. I have installed and configured the Mailcatcher module in accepance.suite.xml like this:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost/development/rd_dev/webroot/
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - MailCatcher
    config:
        MailCatcher:
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1'
            port: '1080'
```

In one test I'm sending an email from the system. I print the text that has put in the email that I send on the screen and first check that this is correct. I can manually see the email appear on in the web browser on the address and port: http://127.0.0.1:1080/ and it also works out to use a method to delete all the messages on the mailcatcher smtp-server, $I->resetEmails().

However **when I use methods to access the content of the email** from the test, for example $I->seeInLastEmail('foo') or $text = $I->grabFromLastEmail("bar"), then I get the error message shown below:

```
There was 1 error:

---------
1) ACT1050-SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept: Send email with      report reminder for one report for the test company to an email address   specified by the user (act1050)
 Test  tests/acceptance/ACT1050-    SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept.php

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException] Server error: `GET  http://127.0.0.1:1080/messages/3.json` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error`  response: Internal server error

Scenario Steps:

36. $I->seeInLastEmail("report") at tests/acceptance/ACT1050-SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept.php:31
35. $I->see("sent 2017-07-29") at tests/acceptance/ACT1050-SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept.php:30
34. $I->see("report") at tests/acceptance/ACT1050-SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept.php:29
33. $I->see("To: carl@example.com") at tests/acceptance/ACT1050-SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept.php:28
32. $I->see("This email has been sent") at tests/acceptance/ACT1050-SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept.php:27
31. $I->click("Send email") at tests/acceptance/ACT1050-SendEmailReportReminderWhenTryingOutServiceCept.php:26

#1  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:65
#2  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:203
#3  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:156
#4  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php:61
#5  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:246
#6  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:223
#7  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:266
#8  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:225
#9  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:62
#10 /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/bin/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:129
```

I have tried to fiddle with the settings for access to directories in httpd.conf-file (and after changed back to normal), but I have not succeded.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: I solved the issue with help from a friend to target the problem and then from this link to handled the problem: https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/201. The problem occured due to that the version of Mailcatcher that I installed didn't support Swedish characters (å, ä and ö). When I changed this to version 0.5.12 (as recommended in the link above), the issue was solved!

Comment: Its good if you managed to do it on your own,  Please post the solution as an answer so it is beneficial for others in future